# Test convergence of the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n^t}{(2i)^n}$ is?

Tags: complex-analysis

Complex Analysis experts! This questions and its problems are different from other existing questions.

I am analyzing the power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n^t}{(2i)^n},$ for convergence, absolute convergence and divergence.

Using root test and $\lim_{n\to \infty} n^{in}=1$ we have

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \lvert(z_n)^{1/n}\rvert= 1/2$ hence is absolutely convergent

I have following confusions,

1. Is this most appropriate test
2. Every absolutely convergent series is convergent? and about converse?
3. My solution is right?
4. what if in statement its $n^n$ in place of $n^i$ ?

Thanks, for your interest and guidance

Answer (score 1):

Ratio test and root test both work fine in this case. The series is absolutely convergent and your proof is fine.

Every absolutely convergent series is convergent and the converse is not true as the example  $\sum \frac {(-1)^{n}} n$ shows.

If you have $n^{n}$ in the numerator the the series becomes divergent. This is because the general term does not tend to $0$. Note that $|\frac {n^{n}} {(2i)^{n}}| \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$.

[$ \frac {n^{n}} {2^{n}} >(\frac  3  2)^{n}$ for $n >3$ and $(\frac  3  2)^{n} \to \infty$].